How can the power of an oscillator be calculated?
I am designing a hartley oscillator and would like to know how much power it consumes. How can I figure out how much power the hartley oscillator consumes mathematically?
edit: I meant mathematically without spice so that i can know how spice does it.


Note that Rc has a comma instead of a decimal point, I believe LTspice will see that as a 4 ohm resistor.

Theoretical math that avoids simulation? Or simulated math that avoids theory?

In the LTspice simulator you appear to be using you can plot the power consumed by holding the alt key and left-clicking the voltage source. On the plot pane you can hold control and left-click the trace name at the top and it will show you average power.
The calculation is simply the voltage times the current, for your schematic it should show that it's plotting V(VCC) * I(V1).

What is RMS power all about?

@Andyaka Oops, was posting from my phone and going from memory, which apparently isn't what it used to be.

ITYM left-click for the average. OP should zoom to an integral number of cycles (or include so many that it doesn't matter much where the averaging interval starts and ends).

The average current consumed by the BJT during oscillation can be calculated as \$ i_{BJT} = i_{DC} I_0(x)\$, where \$i_{DC}\$ is the initial bias current of the transistor, \$ x = \frac{V_{Osc}}{V_{TH}}\$ is the ratio of oscillation amplitude at \$V_{BE}\$ to the thermal voltage, and \$I_0(x)\$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind. Your DC power would then simply be \$V_{CC}(1+
\beta)i_{BJT}\$. I would recommend Communication Circuits: Analysis and Design by Clarke & Hess as an excellent resource on the topic.
